# How to make API call (CRUD) on React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using [Sb-Admin-React](https://github.com/start-react/sb-admin-react). I need to make API call (CRUD) on this framework (Sb-Admin-React), but I have no idea to make it.

May there's anyone can help me to make it out. Thanks

Comment: You have examples in this project source code... [example](https://github.com/start-react/sb-admin-react/blob/master/src/data/queries/news.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isomorphic fetch is [already included](https://github.com/start-react/sb-admin-react/blob/master/docs/data-fetching.md) in Sb-Admin-React.

You can make your regular API calls with fetch. It should look something like:

```
 fetch(apiUrl, {
    method: method,
    headers: headersIfAny,
    body: theDataToSend
  })
  .then(response => /* do something with response */)
  .catch(err => /* do something with err */);
```

You can go through [Isomorphic Fetch readme](https://github.com/matthew-andrews/isomorphic-fetch) for more info